# Web Workers written in Typescript in Webpack 5: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: typescript, webpack, web-worker, webpack-5

Webpack 5 [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/) mentions that `worker-loader` is not needed anymore, and it seems easy for javascript files. However, I am using Typescript, and I'm not able to get my worker.js output file working properly. When I launch load the webworker with `const worker = new Worker(workerPath);`, I get

```js
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Note: my `workerPath` is `"dist/app.worker.js"` and this file exists, but it sadly contains either `import` or `require` statements, which don't work in the browser. I think need to bundle these together, but I'm not sure how. Currently, it contains the following code, and I hoped that auth.ts will be bundled in:

```
import Auth from "./auth";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `worker-loader` or the default webpack config using `module.export = {...}`, I [exported multiple configurations](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations). Specifically, I created 2 entry points (`main` and `worker` in `webpack.config.js`, and used `module.exports = [main, worker]`. In the code, I referenced the second entry point using `const workerPath = "./dist/worker_name.worker.js"`.

## My `webpack.config.js`

```js
const path = require('path')

const main = {
    entry: "./src/index.ts",
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: "dist/"
    },
    context: __dirname,
    devtool: "source-map",
    mode: "development",
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            'src',
            'node_modules'
        ],
        extensions: [
            '.js',
            '.ts',
            '.tsx'
        ],
        plugins: [],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                options: {
                    transpileOnly: true,
                },
            },
        ],
    },
}

const worker = {
    entry: "./src/worker_name.worker.ts",
    output: {
        filename: 'worker_name.worker.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: "dist/"
    },
    target: "webworker",
    devtool: "source-map",
    mode: "development",
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            'src',
            'node_modules'
        ],
        extensions: [
            '.js',
            '.ts',
            '.tsx'
        ],
        plugins: [],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                options: {
                    transpileOnly: true,
                },
            },
        ],
    },
}


module.exports = [main, worker]
```

You can probably refactor the above to make it shorter by sharing code between them.

Comment: This is the only approach that worked for me when using Webpack 5 and Threads.js until Threads gets full Webpack 5 support.